# 128 bit hash without collisions guaranteed

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography

Is there a 128 hashing algorithm (no matter if it is a crypto or non-crypto hashing) that guarantee no collision could occur?

If can guarantee my string would not exceed a specific length (is there such length? - I can guarantee a length less than 100 chars)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't make such an algorithm. If you have a string with **100** characters, you have (let character be in `1..255` range)

```
256**100 == (2**8)**100 == 2**800
```

*different* strings (pontential collisions); **128** bit hash function has `2**128` *different values* only,
since

```
2**128 < 2**800
```

collisions are inevitable: [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle.)

**Edit**: imagine that we have `128`-bit function; what is the maximum length of the string which can be collision free?

```
   256**length = 2**128
(2**8)**length = 2**128
    8 * length = 128
        length = 16
```

So the maximum length is `16` (I've assumed for simplicity that string doesn't contain `'\0'`). If string a unicode one (i.e. has chars in `1..65535` range)

```
     65536**length = 2**128
   (2**16)**length = 2**128
       16 * length = 128
            length = 8
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, Is there a minimum string length that could prevent such collision?

Comment: @Joseph: for arbitrary strings (which has chars `1..255` range) the length is `16`

Comment: For a finite set of input strings, it is possible to generate a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) with no collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make a *mathematical* guarantee that no collision occurs.

But you can make a *practical* guarantee, that the probability of a collision is so low that it's OK for you. One example is [randomly generated UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), where the probability of duplicates is so low that's it's not a problem in practise. The same for [content addressable storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_storage), that typically rely on practical (not mathematical) uniqueness of cryptographic hash functions.

Whether or not the hash algorithm is good enough for you depends on how many items you want to hash, and what probability of collision is acceptable for you. Then you can use the formula in the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) to calculate if 128 bits are sufficient for you.