# Can two bitcoin addresses has same checksum

Tags: bitcoin

I know that checksum is extracted from double sha256 of the ripemd160. So, it must be possible to have two bitcoin addresses to have same checksum though statistically improbable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the same bitcoin address from different public/private keys. This is called a "collision" and you can't have hash functions without collisions (see [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). Also check [128 bit hash without collisions guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924076/128-bit-hash-without-collisions-guaranteed).

Comment: So, if an address is created by using one key pair, can a different key pair can be used to spend the bitcoin as long as both key pairs generate the same bitcoin address?

Comment: @Pessy It seems so, yes.

Comment: And the probability of collision ~ 1/(2^95).